# OpenERP 6.1 web client - set default value (Configuration parameters)

Tags: python, odoo, erp

I need to set up default **Home Action** for *res.user*. Currently is **Home Page** but I want set my custom action. So, I tried create new record for *Settings --> Configuration --> Configuration Parameters* , but when I set field for **Home Action** in field **Field** and set type **Many2One** in field **Type**, field **Value** remains empty list. I can't choose my custom action for new users! Please, correct me if I'm doing something wrong. Is this a bug or normal behavior? Any other solution is welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution. When I click on button **Create** for **res.users** in right side bar, in section **Customize** action **Set Default** appears. Here you can choose default value which appears when **Create** button was pressed.

UPDATE:

All these values you can see in

*Settings --> Customization --> Low Level Objects --> Actions --> User-defined Defaults*

Of course, here you can create new default values.

Answer (score 0):

just an additional note:you can also apply this user defined dafaults with many2many fields like taxes_id field in product model.

however there is a small bug, if you set a default value for many2many fields when you create a new record, many2many field is shown empty, when you save the record you will see it is well recorded with your default value, so if you want to make a record different than the default you have to first save than edit again.